# Cloudinary doesn' t work well with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

This is my first question on the site, my apology if it seems stupid (I did my search but I can't find any solutions)

#### Problem:

I am using Cloudinary for image uploading in my project. It works well for now. But the problem is about WebStorm. It seems that WebStorm can't resolve cloudinary from its package through `require` because all the **methods/variables** of cloudinary are marked as **unresolved** methods/variables, as shown below:

[image: WebStorm warnings]

If I run the server, all the methods with warnings worked well, everything seemed okay while the warnings are really annoying...

Really appreciate if there is any help!

Comment: they aren't resolved in the other editors as well. Seems the Cloudinary type definitions (d.ts files) have to be re-worked. From https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/460#issuecomment-748171559 it seems that work is in progress

Comment: Thanks for the info and edit, really appreciate it!